# Rails as_json includes with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, include, conditional-statements

I have problems to restrict an as_json include by a dynamic attribute:

```
@pirates_ships = @current_account.pirates.as_json(:include => {:ships => {:only => [:id, :name]}}, :only => [:id, :last_name])
```

This for sure gives me all pirates with or without their ships.

But I also need to **restrict the ships by e.g. ships.ocean_id**

I tried resolving it by includes with conditions:

```
pirates.includes(:ships).where("ships.ocean_id = ?", @ocean.id).as_json(...)
```

The restriction works, but now all pirates without a ship are lost.

Also no luck with my own JOIN Syntax.

Any ideas?
Ahoy

**UPDATE**

My solution so far is to manually eager load. This way I can have my dynamic conditions:

```
@pirates = @current_account.pirates
@ships = @current_account.ships.where({:pirate_id.in => @pirates, :ocean_id => @ocean.id})

render :json => { :pirates => @pirates.as_json(...), :ships => @ships.as_json(...) }
```

My Ajax callback can now iterate over :pirates and add for each pirate his ships if any.
(I use a JS template engine clientside to generate the view from the JSON response)

Not very elegant, but performance is important in my case.

I'am still open for better ideas.
I tried dynamic has_many :ships, :conditions => ... 
but that's a bit fiddly.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet would be altering the `@pirates_ships` hash after generating it from `as_json` (I tried multiple variations of includes, etc. and couldn't get anything to work).

```
@pirates_ships = @current_account.pirates.as_json(:include => :ships)
@pirates_ships.each do |pirate|
  pirate[:ships].delete_if{ |ship| ship.ocean_id != @ocean.id }
end

# Now, @pirates_ships should contain ALL pirates, as well as ships for @ocean
```

Comment: That works (voted up). But imagine a pirates world with thousands of ships and still growing. My chief mate would need to count all ships on all oceans each time he must report for a single ocean... This would be a performance hit on our sql map ;-) I'd prefer a clean map from the start.

Comment: Arrgh! I still can't vote up, I'am lacking 15 reputation as a newbie. Sorry!!

Comment: It's definitely not optimized. I've had a similar issue on one of my projects before, and short of manually generating all the JSON one record at a time, I wasn't able to come up with a good way of doing this. Fortunately, my database is relatively small so the iteration over the arrays worked fine for me.